# Google Local Search API

Tags: google-maps, google-local-search

couple of quick questions

1) In the local search results - we can get a lot of parameters like street title, address, city, state, lat, long , url etc
- In order for me to uniquely identify this record - can I consider URL to be unique to this address or concatenation of latitude and longitude

Ref: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GlocalResult

2) In terms of usage, depending upon what user enters, I'm displaying a list of local business for the user to choose. Now when a user selects a particular business address - is it legal for me to store that business address along with lat and longitude information in my database for future look ups.
I've seen a lot of blogs talking about storing the lat/long info but just want to be sure that i'm not violating and google rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The url is probably unique, but I cannot see any guarantee that it will not change. Why don't you use a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) to uniquely identify the records?
2. Note article 1.4 in the [Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html):

   > You agree that when using the Service, You will not, and will not permit users or other third parties to:
   >
   > ...
   >
   > copy, store, archive, republish, or create a database of Google Search Results, in whole or in part, directly or indirectly, except that You may display Google Search Results that have been "clipped" through an end user-requested action, provided that You comply with the attribution requirements described in Section 2.3 below;

   The Google Maps API has similar restrictions. I would suggest getting in touch with Google regarding this issue. (IANAL).

Comment: Hey Daniel - this was the article I was referring to - where they pass different addresses to the webservice and store the lat long in the database - http://www.developer.com/article.php/10915_3621981_2/Performing-HTTP-Geocoding-with-the-Google-Maps-API.htm

Comment: @Gubloo: It seems from that the Terms of Use of the Maps API explicitly forbid this: Check article 10.3 http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html... *"you must not... pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily, securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;"*